# How to validate a form using AngularJS or ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I want to verify that all inputs in a form are filled correctly before submitting the information to the data store.

This is an example of a form element in my application as generated by ASP.NET:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.RegisterPassword, new {placeholder = "Password", @class = "email text-input" })
```

How can I do this using either ASP.NET or AngularJS?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two paths, I recommend the first one

1 - Use AngularJS form validation, this [Article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) explains it really nicely with `ng-messages`

2 - You can preform all the kind of checks you want after clicking on the button using `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Razor with Angularjs, I never tried that but here is the post you can check for validation in angularjs

Check demo before implementing, there is two types of validation one is by css and other by ngMessage.

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1205/angularjs-validation-with-css-and-ngmessage-with-demo